# How to send ether from sender account to a given account

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain, remix

I am new to solidity and trying to develop a small smart contract. I want to send ether from the sender account to a given account. But I always get this error "**VM error: revert. revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Reason provided by the contract: "Insufficient balance". Debug the transaction to get more information.**"

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.0.0 <0.9.0;

contract SimpleTranaction {
    address  payable public receiver =  0xAb8483F64d9C6d1EcF9b849Ae677dD3315835cb2;

    function sendTo(uint amount)   public  payable  {
      
        require(msg.sender.balance < amount, "Insufficient balance");
        receiver.transfer(amount); 
    }
}
```

I use Remix IDE. The sender account has an enough balance
[image]

What could be the reason for this? Am I doing something theoretically wrong? If so what is the best approach to do this?

Answer (score 0):

First you really should not use such a big range of pragma. ">=0.8.0" should be fine for the moment.

```
require(msg.sender.balance < amount, "Insufficient balance");
```

Checks if the balance of the sending Externally Owned Account (EOA) is smaller than "amount".

If you change the condition to ">=" in runs through.

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.0;
contract SimpleTransaction {
address payable receiver = payable(0xAb8483F64d9C6d1EcF9b849Ae677dD3315835cb2);

function sendTo(uint256 amount)   external  payable  {
    require(msg.sender.balance >= amount, "Error because balance");
    receiver.transfer(amount); 
}
```

}

Comment: toothleth_byte thanks for your response. I changed the code as you proposed. But I get the same error. What I dont understand is when I call receiver.transfer(amount) is it transfer from EOA to the receiver or from the contract address to the receiver? . When I enter the same amount into the Value field of Remix, the transaction was successfully completed.

Comment: address.transfer tries to send ether from the Smart Contract Owned Account to the receiver address. 
That said, you use a very big range of pragmas, I will change my answer a little bit with a working example.